# Want to extract specific data to another cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

```
000008()-24/25 MELFORD COURT, HARDWICK GRANGE WOOLSTON WARRINGTON, WAI 4RZ ENGLAND
```

I want to extract all data i.e. the whole address after `000008()-` in another cell in Excel but don't know how to do it

Comment: Can you show some more sample data. A formula may work on this string but may not work on others. It would be better to show some more samples to generalize the formula

Comment: Why the Access tag? Can it be removed as not sure relevant. If you always want the string after the first - there are lots of examples of this on StackOverflow using functions like Find/Search combined with other string functions (Left,Right, Mid, Len....)

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: 000009 (   ) - ABDUL QADIR MANSLON, HUSBAND ROAD, PUNJABI CLUB, KHARADAR,  KARACHI
000007 (   ) - CS-49, SHOP # 02 PRINCE
000014 (   ) - (64) 11/A, AL NOOR AUTO MARKET, PLAZA SQUARE ( PREEDY ST. ) SADDAR, KARACHI.
NA                    A.B. TRADERS                                 Karachi              021-2727313/272303                                                             021-2726752/2773322       No
000015 (   ) - FL-1/11, 2ND FLOOR, ALEEM

Comment: As per the data you have provided i can come up with this, if the rest of your data is different than the provided one, the formula may not work..

=TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+1,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2))) 

It is extracting the address from the cell A1

Answer (score -1):

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-9)
```

will achieve what you say you want.

[image]